# a line without a point in the plane is neither closed nor open

Tags: general-topology

This question is in Mathematics for Economist, Chapter 12: The section on closed sets has examples (including the one below) that are neither closed nor open.

I need to show that line minus a point in the plane is neither open or closed. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Some point must not be an interior point, and some limit point must not be contained in it...